# Передача пароля боту в Telegram (авторизация в сторонних сервисах)

Tags: telegram-bot, авторизация, интернет-магазин

Задача - связать аккаунт *Telegram* с учётной записью интернет-магазина. Какие существуют способы сделать это безопасно? Имеет ли смысл запрашивать логин-пароль?

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы отображались звездочки при вводе пароля?

Comment: Также как это делают в других сервисах вроде google, yandex, twitter и тд? Сделать токен и пользоваться только им (посмотрите на бота для гитхаба).

Comment: А звездочки это глупо. Никакой сторонний сервис не должен иметь доступа к паролю ни в каком виде: ни пересылать пароль серверу с магазином явно, ни хранить хеш пароля.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для своего случая нашёл более простое решение - предлагаю пользователю перейти по ссылке на сайт интернет-магазина для авторизации. В случае успешной авторизации - связываю идентификатор клиента на сайте с идентификатором чата в *Telegram*, затем делаю редирект пользователя со страницы авторизации на бота.

---

Таким образом, весь пласт связанных с авторизацией задач с бота снимается за счёт (уже реализованного) функционала на сайте.

Answer (score -2):

```
if(mb_substr($message,0,6)=="/pass "){

            $pass = mb_substr($message,6); // берем параль после /pass 

}
```

Можно так, брать сообщение считать от начала строки