# Информирование клиентов о заказах в Telegram

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли отправлять сообщения пользователям из своего сайта в Telegram? Каждому клиенту должно приходить уведомление о новом заказе на сайте. Есть ли какие-то варианты или только отправка сообщение в чат боту?

Comment: либо делаете бота и садите всех клиентов на него, тогда можно работать по [такой схеме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545045/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82-telegram-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85/547648#547648)

Comment: либо делаете это через [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/api#telegram-api), но это на порядок сложнее

Comment: так же может быть полезно - [простое связывание аккаунтов телеграма и вашего веб-ресурса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537887/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B2-telegram-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85)

Comment: Чтобы был chat id должен каждый клиент написать боту?

Comment: *Чтобы был chat id должен каждый клиент написать боту* - обязательно, боты не могут инициировать чат первыми

Comment: Можно ли делать рассылку по логину пользователя в telegram через API?

Comment: что такое логин? у пользователей нет логинов, есть юзернеймы и есть они не у всех

Comment: Такого вида @username или рассылку зная только телефон

Comment: я дал ссылку на документацию, вы смотрели там прежде, чем всё это спрашивать?

Comment: Английский плохо знаю. Подскажите можно ли  такое?

Comment: Из ссылки выше: "... затем делаю редирект пользователя со страницы авторизации на бота." Т.е. сюда редирект https://telegram.me/username

Comment: Да, где юзернейм - это юзернейм бота

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.